Debugger Compatibility with Android 15 (Rad Studio 12.1)
I've just started using FireMonkey targeting Android to try and build a personal app on Android.  I was using the 11.3 Community Edition and when trying to run with debugging, the debugger would timeout and say the device wasn't responding even though the device was visible and I could even get logcat information using Device Lens.  My test phone has Android 15 which I suspected to be a problem, so I upgraded my CE version to 12.1, given that Embarcadero implies that it is compatible with Android 15.  Now, even when running a blank Android app, I get a class Segmentation fault(11).  I'm using the standard SDK that is installed via the RAD studio installer.  Running an app without the debugger seems to be fine.  Does the debugger work with Android 15 devices?  Are there some special steps that need to be taken to get it to work?

